# Pass a list from ajax function to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a list and a string to the controller. When I debug I can see all the information is well taken by the function. The problem is that the list of users the controller receives is empty.

Here is the JS function code:

```
      $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          var selected_values = new Array();
          $(document).ready(function () {
              selected_values = []; // initialize empty array 
              $(".checked:checked").each(function () {
                  selected_value.push($(this).val());
              });
          });
          $.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  lstUserName: selected_values,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
```

And here is the action:

```
        public IEnumerable<DateTime> getInfoByDate(string strDate, string lstUserName)
    {
        CareDB context = new CareDB();

        SqlParameter Date = new SqlParameter("@Date", strDate);
        SqlParameter userName = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", lstUserName);

        object[] parameters = new object[] { Date, userName };

        IEnumerable<DateTime> lst = context.ReleaseDate.SqlQuery("_UserInformationByDate @Date, @EmployeeName", parameters).ToList();

        context.Dispose();
        context = null;
        return lst;
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit**

```
      $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          var selected_values = new Array();
          $(document).ready(function () {
              selected_values = []; // initialize empty array 
              $(".checked:checked").each(function () {
                  selected_values.push($(this).val());
              });
          });
          $.ajax({
              url: 'EmployeeDate',
              datatype: "application/json",
              traditional:true, 
              data: {
                  lstUserName: selected_values,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Have you tried changing the datatype of lstUserName to a list or an array? Example: List<string> lstUserName or string[] lstUserName.  The value that you are trying to pass to the action is an array so I think the data type should also be an array or a list.

Comment: Is that a GET method? You would need to set `traditional: true` and change the parameter to `string[] lstUserName`

Comment: Where do you put the traditional parameter?

Comment: Its one of the ajax options

Comment: You have `$(document).ready()` inside the `click` event of the button. there is no need for that. just keep the `var selected_values = [];
    $(".checked:checked").each(function () {
        selected_values.push($(this).val());
    });`(the `var selected_values = new Array();` is redundant with `selected_values = []`

Comment: `.val()` returns a string, even from a date picker. No point in calling `.toString()` on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your `selected_values` which is an array, but your method's parameter is a `string` only. Change to

**In the backend** you can change the method's parameter to receive an array of strings.

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> getInfoByDate(string strDate, string[] lstUserName)
{
    CareDB context = new CareDB();

    SqlParameter Date = new SqlParameter("@Date", strDate);
    SqlParameter userName = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeName", lstUserName);

    object[] parameters = new object[] { Date, userName };

    IEnumerable<DateTime> lst = context.ReleaseDate.SqlQuery("_UserInformationByDate @Date, @EmployeeName", parameters).ToList();

    context.Dispose();
    context = null;
    return lst;
}
```

Or **in the frontend** you can change your data

```
data: {
         lstUserName: selected_values.join(' '),
         strDate: date  },
```

Edited:

```
$.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  lstUserName: selected_values,
                  strDate: date
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
```

Comment: You are right, I haven't see that.. my mistake. Anyway is still the same behaviour

Comment: @SomeAnonymousPerson try to add `dataType="json"`

Comment: Where should I add that parameter?

Comment: This will just send a space-separated list of values to the server, where server code will have to split to convert to a real `List<String>`. not very elegant.

Comment: @TsahiAsher which version? Backend or Frontend? See the answer. I have suggested two versions.Of course the first is the best.And remove your downvote

Comment: @SomeAnonymousPerson Also, `dataType` is used to interpret the response from the server. It has nothing to do with how you

Comment: @TsahiAsher It is only by your judgement

Comment: did you? I do that for my work. You must at least set `traditional: true` in the `.ajax()` config.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to send data to an MVC controller:

### As JSON

You need to send a JSON string, and an `application/json` MIME-type header. This has two configs in the `.ajax()` method:

1. Stringify your object:

`data: JSON.stringify({
                  lstUserName: selected_values,
                  strDate: date
              }),`

2. `contentType: 'application/json'`

### As form data

1. leave the `data` config as an object, but bear in mind that jQuery will construct a query string out of it, with each property as a key. In your case, `lstUserName=user1&lstUserName=user2&strDate=1/1/2016`
2. set the `traditional` config to `true`, in order to generate the above string for the lstUserName array.

Then, you can have your controller accept a `DateTime strDate, string[] lstUserName`. But I would have changed the names to remove the prefixes, from both the client and the server.

A final note: I'm not sure what's the return data type of `.val()` on a date picker, but if it's a Date, then `.toString()` is a bad choice. You should return something in a format that can be parsed by `DateTime.Parse()`, which MVC uses to parse date values. perhaps using `.toDateString()` or `.toISOString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this method..

```
var data = { 'user_ids[]' : []};

$(".checked:checked").each(function () {
  data['user_ids[]'].push($(this).val());
});


$.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  lstUserName: data,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
```

Let me know if you still not able to do it.

Comment: Its the same behaviout. The problem is that the values are getting right, but are not passing it right to the controller

Comment: This won't work. MVC doesn't understand names like `user_ids[]`. You have to send `user_id=user&user_id=user2&user_id=user3` etc. to send an array.

Comment: Quite positive. MVC maps parameter names from the POST data to parameter names in the controller action. And you can't name a parameter with `[]` in C#.