# how to pass list of strings in ajax to controller mvc. I dont access to come controller values

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, model-view-controller

My jquery function is send list of strings 'checkKhbVals' to controller;

```
 var checkKhbVals=["8","9"];
 var url = '@Url.Action("AkademikPersonel_GetMultiCheckBoxKurum", "Doktor")';
            $.getJSON(url, { 'checkKhbVals': JSON.stringify(checkKhbVals) }, function (result, status, xhr) {
                filterMultiCheck.container.empty();               
                filterMultiCheck.checkSource.data(result);
                filterMultiCheck.createCheckBoxes();
            });
```

And my controller is;

```
 public JsonResult AkademikPersonel_GetMultiCheckBoxKurum(List<string> checkKhbVals)
        {           
            var result = Business.Kurum.GetKurumMultiCheckBox();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

MY data is coming to controller but I dont access to values. Here is the my screenshot;
[image: my screenshot]

Comment: use `checkKhbVals.ToString()` instead of `JSON.stringify(checkKhbVals)`

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify`, just provide the `checkKhbVals` directly in the object

Comment: You have to set the `contenType` to `'application/json'` and use `JSON.stringify({checkKhbVals: checkKhbVals})`(easier to use the `ajax()` method for this)

Comment: When I sent directly checkKhbVals in my controller parametre is null @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: To set config `traditional: true` helped me
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475381/pass-a-list-from-ajax-function-to-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem. I use ajax post in this;

```
var da = $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                global: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("AkademikPersonel_GetMultiCheckBoxKurum", "Doktor")',
                data: { 'checkKhbVals': checkKhbVals },
                success: function(data)
                {                    
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

controller parametre is List < string >

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `stringify`

use `checkKhbVals.ToString()` instead of `JSON.stringify(checkKhbVals)`

Comment: I use tostring() but screenshot is; checkKhbList[0]-->"7,8" in controller parametre @Parth Trivedi

Comment: use `List<int>` and remove `.ToString()`

Comment: @user3452425 have removed `.ToString()` only direct Array pass.

Comment: @user3452425 you can use `$.post`

Comment: what is difference $.post and $.ajax? @ParthTrivedi